# what improvements do i need to make to my form submission (for email) to stop the spam i am receiving and make my form more secure?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Every morning at exactly 10:53am I am hit with 1-2 blank emails by some sort of entity using my send.php file.

i know this is a result of my php send file on my website, but i dont have much knowledge of php. I spent a lot of time several weeks ago looking for clear cut information telling me how to setup my input form with php to just get it to initially send and got this far. But I know there are some absolutely glaringly obvious security holes in my code.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong on my form to lock it down so i dont get hit with spam anymore.

i have a javascript honeypot, which is just an input field that if the hidden field gets selected it changes a value from true to false and the form will no longer submit the form it will instead give the user an alert saying they have successfully submitted the form, and the page just reloads (probably not that great of a solution).

i went ahead and replaced my email with the some@email.com

```
<?php
  $sname = $_POST['name'];
  $slastname = $_POST['last-name'];
  $semail = $_POST['email'];
  $semailconfirm = $_POST['confirm-email'];
  $sphone = $_POST['phone-number'];
  $smessage = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );



  $formerrors = false;



  if ($sname === '') :
    echo "<div>Sorry, first name is a required field</div>";
  endif; //input field empty

  if (!(preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+/', $sname)) ) :
    echo "<div>Sorry, first name doesnt follow the allowed pattern</div>";
  endif; //pattern doesnt match

  if ($slastname === '') :
    echo "<div>Sorry, last name is a required field</div>";
  endif; //input field empty

  if (!(preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+/', $slastname)) ) :
    echo "<div>Sorry, last name doesnt follow the allowed pattern</div>";
  endif; //pattern doesnt match


  if ($semail === '') :
    echo "<div>Sorry, email is a required field</div>";
  endif; //input field empty

  if ($semailconfirm !== $semail) :
    echo "<div>Sorry, emails must match</div>";
  endif; //input field empty

  if ($smessage === '') :
    echo "<div>Sorry, your message has no content</div>";
  endif; //input field empty



  if (!($formerrors)) :
    $to       = "some@email.com";
    $subject  = "From $sname $slastname -- $semail -- $sphone";
    $message  = "$sname filled out the form";

    $replyto  = "From: $semail \r\n".
                "Reply-To: some@email.com \r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $smessage)):
      $msg = "Thanks for filling out my contact form";
    else:
      $msg = "problem sending message";
    endif; //mail form data

  endif; //check for errors


?>
```

the email i get every day says

> From   --  --

and doesnt have anything in the text body

Comment: Obfuscate the email address and implement ReCaptcha. You can download and examine implementation examples here:
https://github.com/google/recaptcha

Comment: don't forget the Irish! Last names like `O'Brian` should be allowed to pass the last name test. Also hyphenated names (for the married folk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the `$formerrors` so

```
 if ($sname === '') :
    echo "<div>Sorry, first name is a required field</div>";
  endif; //input field empty
```

and your other checks only output an error but still process the form.

Try:

```
 if ($sname === '') :
    echo "<div>Sorry, first name is a required field</div>";
    $formerrors = true;
  endif; //input field empty
```

Comment: this really did help alot :)

Answer (score 1):

Recaptcha is the only cost effective way, so I wouldn't give up on it. It's pretty simple:

1. Since you're using php, here is the form you need  (add the "php" part):

   ```
       <form method="post" action="verify.php">
       <?php
         require_once('recaptchalib.php');
         $publickey = "your_public_key"; // you got this from the signup page
         echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
       ?>
             <input type="submit" />
        </form>
   ```
2. You then in a verify.php (or wherever you submit the form data) the recpatcha validation:

   ```
   <?php
     require_once('recaptchalib.php');
     $privatekey = "your_private_key";
     $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                   $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                   $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                   _POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);      
     if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
        die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
        "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
     } else {
        // Your code here to handle a successful verification
     }
     ?>
   ```
3. That's it.

Comment: thanks for this, my form is on a regular html passing the info to a php page, will i have to do a little tweaking to make this work?

Comment: @Aron If you like the answer, upvote to give it credibility. There's nothing to tweak, just insert your public and private keys where mentioned in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to set your `$formerrors` flag to `true` when there was an error.  Try something like:

```
if (trim($sname) == '') 
{
    $formerrors = true;
    echo "<div>Sorry, first name is a required field</div>";
}
```